# How to run UIAutomation using Jenkins?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to combine Instruments UIAutomation with the CI by Jenkins.

In the Jenkins project's configurations I defined a call a script:

```
sh buildAndTest.sh
```

That all it does is to call the uitest

```
#!/bin/sh 
make uitest
```

uitest is defined inside Makefile, and it makes the call to Instruments:

```
/usr/bin/instruments -t pathToTemplate/MyTemplate.tracetemplate  pathToSimulator/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/a_very_long_name/Main.app
```

This code works in the terminal and when I call "make uitest".
It doesn't work when Jenkins executes the script, and the console outputs:

> Instruments Usage Error : (null)
>   make: *** [uitest] Error 254
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

Any ideas how to integrate these two?

Answer (score 1):

I just made it and it was a bit painfull.

## Step 1.1 : Build your app using Xcode Plugin with the simulator SDK

[image: sdk]

## Step 1.2 : Define a readable build directory

[image]

## Step 3 : Add a Shell build step with following line :

```
instruments -t ~/Desktop/test1.tracetemplate __YOUR_BUILD_PATH__/_YOUR_APP_.app
```

Works for me. Tell me if you have any trouble

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the Jenkins slave agent is running as a user of the system AND that the system is logged into the desktop.  If the desktop isn't visible, UI automation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Another reson could be you are giveing respective paths. Replace it with full qulified paths if any.